# Boot Windows 7 in a new machine

Tags: windows-7, drivers, repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change computer but retain hard disk](https://superuser.com/questions/197680/how-to-change-computer-but-retain-hard-disk)
>   [What would happen if I take my hard drive out of my current PC and put it in a new PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/412498/what-would-happen-if-i-take-my-hard-drive-out-of-my-current-pc-and-put-it-in-a-n)

I had to buy a desktop since my laptop died because of a glass of wine.
I want to boot from my laptop's Windows 7 in my new machine (every piece of hardware is different but it's still intel/ati), how can I manage that?

Today, WIndows 7 is crashing at the very beginning of it's loading. I've read about Sysprep.exe (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html) and I wonder if I still do that even if my system doesn't boot or if there is a similar bootable tool?

I can't reinstall from scratch because I haven't note the Win7 product key and I'm not able to find it using ProduKey.

Answer (score 2):

> I had to buy a desktop since my laptop died because of a glass of
>   wine. I want to boot from my laptop's Windows 7 in my new machine
>   (every piece of hardware is different but it's still intel/ati), how
>   can I manage that?

It might not be possible the HDD in your laptop might be damaged.  If its not damaged then Acronis True Home Image would be able to with the Plus Pack image the entire hdd and allow you restore it on a different hardware configuration.

> Today, WIndows 7 is crashing at the very beginning of it's loading.
>   I've read about Sysprep.exe
>   (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html)
>   and I wonder if I still do that even if my system doesn't boot or if
>   there is a similar bootable tool?

Its crashing because you are trying to boot on different hardware.  Until you resolve that conflict even if it wasn't crashing at the point it is, Windows wouldn't like being booted on different hardware, I suggest just transfer the personal date and reinstall programs.

> I can't reinstall from scratch because I haven't note the Win7 product
>   key and I'm not able to find it using ProduKey.

Even if you do purchase Acronis True Home Image, your license is not legally allowed to run on anything but the laptop, so you won't be able to activate it.

Comment: Wrong, wrong wrong. My HDD is ok, I can access every file on it. I know it's crashing because hardware has changed, what I ask is how to restore Win7 with something like Sysprep.exe. And my licence key isn't tied to my laptop, it's a regular licence, not an OEM one.

Comment: @koskoz - Sysprep doesn't work that way, you have to have the installation functional in the first place.  Just reinstall it.

Comment: @koskoz - You indicated you had a laptop, this would indicate you had an OEM license, my answer is still valid.  Your system is crashing because of the hardware configuration changes.  My suggested solution using Acronis would work with a normal retail windows license.